# Create wrapper with only two function generics

Tags: typescript, generics

Apologies if the question title is vague

I have 2 functions called `fn1` and `fn2`

I want to create a wrapper function which takes in one of those functions and their arguments and executes it. i.e

```js
const fn1 = (a: string, b: string) => a + b;
const fn2 = (a: number) => a * a;

const wrapper = (fn, ...args) => fn(...args);
wrapper(fn, 1, 2)
```

I'm not sure how to add the typings in typescript such that type check is able to infer the arguments and errors if any other function is passed in other than `fn1` and `fn2`

The furthest I got is

```js
const wrapper = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  fn: T,
  ...args: Parameters<T>
): ReturnType<T> => fn(...args);
```

The parameter inference works fine here.

But I want it to error on type check if any other function is passed in

I tried changing the generic to be like this

```js
const wrapper = <T extends typeof fn1 | typeof fn2>(
  fn: T,
  ...args: Parameters<T>
): ReturnType<T> => fn(...args);
```

However typescript gives me an error saying `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter`

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVKb5m) work for you?  There are lots of caveats; you can't really restrict the inputs to either `fn1` or `fn2`, and using generics this way opens up some situations you weren't anticipating.  I don't see how such a wrapper is better than just using `fn1` and `fn2` individually, but maybe there's a compelling use case that isn't motivated by the example code?  Anyway, if you think that works for you I can write up an answer; let me know.

Comment: @jcalz you've actually made a very valid point by illustrating those unanticipated use cases. Thanks for that!

Comment: So do you want to see an answer which explains what's going on here?  Or do you want to edit or otherwise change your question in light of the issues with the `wrapper` approach?

Comment: well my question is flawed but it be awesome if you'd put it down as an answer incase if someone runs into this question